# vb 6 compile error 'user-defined type not defined'

Tags: vb6

There is error 'user-defined type not defined' I got in vb 6 when I was tried to compile the code. can anybody tell me what I need to do to solve this error. following is the line for which I got the error

```
objINI As clsMPT_INI_COnfig
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the class file that contains that class back to the project.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create an instance of clsMPT_INI_COnfig. You have to create it as a class or to make sure that you have imported the correct libraries which have this class.

clsMPT_INI_COnfig is not VB pre-defined class. So it cannot be called implicitly without targeting its original source.